# Plot3D[] problems

Tags: plotting

I have a function with x and y variables. When I'm trying to Plot3D[] it, some kind of hole appears on the surface. However, the surface is continious, I can show it with a simple Plot[].

Image of the problem: [image]

Mathematica code:

```
Clear[f, x, y]
f := (72.2131829904166*Sin[1.9*ArcTan[10.71*x]])/
   Sqrt[1 + 1255.9935999999998*y^2] + 
  Cos[1.081*
     ArcTan[ArcTan[(6.461*(0.009 + x))/
        Sqrt[1 + 17.606416*(0.015 + y)^2]]]]*
   Sec[1.081*
     ArcTan[ArcTan[
       0.058149/
        Sqrt[1 + 17.606416*(0.015 + y)^2]]]]*(104.0077987898286 - 
     1362.512886611634*
      Sin[1.193*
        ArcTan[17.690631066239558*(0.003 + y) + 
          1.4727273456333767*(0.003 + 1.*y - 
             0.056527095967106554*
              ArcTan[0.053071893198718675 + 
                17.690631066239558*y])*(12.048192771084336 + 
             1.*Sign[0.003 + y])]])
Plot3D[f, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -2, 2}]
x := 0
Plot[f, {y, -1, 1}]
```

Any suggestions to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6):

The problem appears to be caused by the default setting for `Exclusions`. Normally this is used to exclude singularities and the like, but the exclusion that `Plot3D` computes is spurious for your case.

```
Plot3D[f, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -2, 2}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The quality is not great, so I would also suggest increasing the number of plot points:

```
Plot3D[f, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -2, 2}, Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]